# convert json into Value pairs

Tags: java, json, dictionary, jackson

I have Json(entire format of json can vary everytime) string as follows,

```
{"domain": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "Content",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem1": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]   
  }
}}
```

which i have converted to a map,which has the key and value as follows,

```
Map<String, Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
jsonMap = mapper.readValue(jsonString,new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>(){});

KEY :domain 
VALUE :{id=file, popup={menuitem=[{value=New, onclick=CreateNewDoc()}, {value=Open, onclick=OpenDoc()}, {value=Close, onclick=CloseDoc()}],}, value=Content}
```

How to access each value by passing its name to the map,like

```
map.get(id) = file
map.get(popup) = {menuitem=[{value=New, onclick=CreateNewDoc()}, {value=Open, onclick=OpenDoc()}, {value=Close, onclick=CloseDoc()}]}
map.get(value) = Content
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What's the result that you obtain?

Comment: I m currently trying to split the map that i converted earlier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get from the map the inner field you need to use a very uncomfortable syntax like this:

```
((Map<String, Object>)jsonMap.get("domain")).get("id") // returns "file"
```

I think that you can read your json in a convenient class that you can create manually. 
The class will have all the fields contained in the json and you will have access to them using *get* methods.

```
class DomainClass {
     public InnerDomain domain;
}

class MenuItem {
     public String value;
     public String onclick;
}

class PopupClass {
    public List<MenuItem> menuitem1;

}

class InnerDomain {
     public String id;
     public String value;
     public PopupClass popup;
}
```

The class *DomainClass* is the main class that you need to use to deserialize your json. Using jackson is pretty easy and it looks like the method that you've used in your case:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
DomainClass domainObj = mapper.readValue(jsonString, DomainClass.class);
// print the id field
System.out.println(domainObj.domain.id);
```

Comment: Thanks.But the format of Json may vary every time so it is not possible to maintain a POJO

Comment: Are you sure? Which is the field that could change?

Comment: It may be from diffrent domains so there is chance for entire JSon may vary

Comment: Maybe you can find a specific structure that remains the same, which will grant to you to define a base class. After that, you can use inheritance to generate a specific POJO class for each domains. Could be good for you?